# Are there convention tags in python?

Tags: python, pep8

Since PEP0008 is not enforced, is there no code tag that say's that the author used PEP0008? Just so you know before using the code if it is 4 spaces or tabbed code, or other things in the convention.

Comment: Just run `pep8` on the code.

Comment: hmm, is that a program I can run or something?

Comment: A simple web search gives this: https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle

Comment: Thanks :) I will look into it!